# What code for the iPhone so the user can change the font size in text view by clicking some buttons?

Tags: iphone, button, textview, font-size

How do I implement code for the iPhone so the user can change the font size in text view by clicking some buttons? (UITextView usage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wire up the buttons to IBActions. Create your interface with an outlet for your UITextView (`textView`) and the current font size (`fSize`).

Within the IBAction put this code:

```
- (IBAction) fontPlusDown {
    fSize++;
    UIFont *newFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fSize];
    [textView setFont:newFont];
}
```

Adjust the code for reduction (fSize--).

Answer (score 0):

Use `[textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithSize:yourdesiredSize]]` when you tap on a button.